# Convert HTML to word file ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

How to convert ruby file in word file i.e (docx file). For pdf, we prawn gem. But is there any gem for word file. I am trying to convert my html file in word file so that it can be editable for user too. What should do in that case ? I was planning to convert that file in word file. Will it be possible or not.

Comment: `f = File.new('myword.docx', 'w')  f.write(File.read('my_html.html')) f.close`...try this thanks

Comment: @RajarshiDas: why not just do `FileUtils.cp`

Comment: what do you want to copy? @kabie There many other ways by line by line using `File.readlines`

Comment: do you want to export to doc using rails?

Answer (score 1):

### If you are using Rails:

#### in initializers/mime_types.rb:

```
Mime::Type.register 'application/vnd.ms-word', :msword
```

#### in your controller:

say you want to export show action:

```
def show
  @item = Item.find params[:id]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.xml { render :xml => @item }
    format.msword { set_header('msword', "#{@item.title}.doc") }
    format.pdf do
        render :pdf => 'Coming soon...', :layout => false
    end
  end
 end
```

#### define set_header in application_controller.rb:

```
def set_header(p_type, filename)
  case p_type
    when 'xls'
     headers['Content-Type'] = "application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8'"
     headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=\"#{filename}\""
     headers['Cache-Control'] = ''

    when 'msword'
     headers['Content-Type'] = "application/vnd.ms-word; charset=UTF-8"
     headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=\"#{filename}\""
     headers['Cache-Control'] = ''

   end
 end
```

#### now define a show.msword.erb  #you can use any template handler like haml etc.

```
YOUR HTML HERE TO EXPORT TO DOC
AS LIKE NORMAL ERB TEMPLATE
```

Comment: The file gets created, but when I open it I have gibberish and word asks me to convert the format

Answer (score 0):

Use htmltoword gem.
https://github.com/nickfrandsen/htmltoword

it hasn't been updated since November 2015, but works well.