# How to convert html ( which contains CSS and some designing ) to MS Word Doc in rails 3.X version?

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I need to convert HTML ( which contains CSS and some designing ) to WORD DOC in rails 3.x version. Please suggest the way / gem / plug-in available for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep the CSS, this may not be easily possible.  There is [another SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372210/convert-html-to-word-file) that may help, by manipulating the MIME types available for Rails and allowing your controller to use that mime type.

If you just want the text, check out [strip_tags](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/strip_tags) for Rails.